# How do I send one user a private message in a facebook app?

Tags: facebook, messaging

I'm trying to make a [mafia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mafia_%28party_game%29)-like game on Facebook, and to do this I would need to be able to tell the mafia users that they are 'it' if you will without telling everyone else involved in a given session that they are 'it' and thus defeat the purpose of the app in the first place.

I have checked other sources, which were people asking to mass-message people or people were asking about iOS programming via facebook.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Use the Request Dialog 2.0 API.
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/requests/